# Java class that return itself

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need  a class able to return instances of itself. I like method used by a singleton pattern that return only once instance of class. But I need that it return more than one instance.

This is  my singleton pattern. How can I modify it to get it able to return more than one instance?

```
public class GrigliaImpl implements Griglia{

    private  static GrigliaImpl istanza;
    private JTextField[][] griglia;   
    private Color color;

    public  GrigliaImpl(){

    }


    @Override
    public int getColumn() {
        return griglia[0].length;
    }

    public JTextField[][] getMatrice(){

        return this.griglia;
        }

    @Override
    public int getRow() {
        return griglia.length;
    }


    @Override
    public void setColor(Color x) {
        this.color=x;

    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void set(int row,int column){
    this.griglia= new JTextField[row][column];
    }

    public static GrigliaImpl getIstanza(){
    if(istanza == null){
        istanza = new GrigliaImpl();
    }
    return istanza;
    }

}
```

Comment: doesn't look like a singleton to me...

Comment: If you are using Singleton then make your constructor `private`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are controversial. If you want to have a singleton - then you will have one instance of this class by definition. If you want to have many instances, then it can't be singleton.

To create a singleton, you need to make your constructor private and add static method to get an instance of your class, which is kept as a static field. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

If you want to return the same instance of class, after invoking its methods, consider using Builder pattern (http://java.dzone.com/articles/dive-builder-pattern).

```
public class GrigliaImpl implements Griglia {

private static GrigliaImpl instance;

private GrigliaImpl() {
}

public static GrigliaImpl getInstance() {
if (instance == null) {
instance = GrigliaImpl();
}
return instance;
}

public GrigliaImpl doSomething() {
// do something
return this;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about the factory pattern:

```
public class MyClass() {
}

public class MyClassFactory() {
    public static getNewInstance() {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

The factory method can be included in your class, you don't need a separate factory class.

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of every class that has a public contructor is to create and return new instances of that class using new operator. but if you specifically want instances through a getInstanceMethod than make constructor private and

replace

```
   public static GrigliaImpl getIstanza(){
      if(istanza == null){
        istanza = new GrigliaImpl();
      }
       return istanza;
     }
```

with

```
   public static GrigliaImpl getIstanza(){
        return new GrigliaImpl();
    }
```

But to me that does not serve any purpose. But you can still do it :)

Comment: why bother do that and not just call `new GrigliaImpl();` since his constructor is public...

Comment: accidentally posted half answer. just edited again :)